# Trying to sign up on instagram with python: https:/instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am having trouble, as everything I have tried does not work. I have tried using python requests. Unfortunately, this does not work because the form is loaded 1 or so seconds after the webpage, making a post request impossible. Grudgingly, I switched to selenium. However, I cannot locate elements by xpath, id, or class because they are all loaded dynamically and randomized each time the web page loads. Is there any other way to possibly sign up?

Requests: When attempting to pass a post request. It fails because the page/form hasn't loaded yet (see URL in title)

```
m = {}
m["fullName"] = "test"
requests.post(url, data=m)
```

Selenium Attempt: Does not work because ids/class names/ etc are randomized each time.

```
email_field =  driver.find_element_by_id("f2e3acfde5540d")
name_field = driver.find_element_by_id("f15a1d5523914b")
username_field = driver.find_element_by_id("ff9c874585158")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("f233cff115218c8")
```

Comment: Please include code and error messages. We can't help you without information.

Comment: You should use the API to get data from instagram. https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: You don't provide any useful information for us to answer your question.

Comment: @nosklo The API does not provide a method to sign up.

Comment: @bad of course, it uses OAuth which is the preferred way

Comment: OAuth logs in, does not allow anyone to sign up because you need an api account, and therefore an instagram account to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example, how to login/sign up to the instagram via Selenium using xpath selectors. I wrote this with a selenium wrapper [Elementium](https://github.com/actmd/elementium) for less code. But, you can use the same selectors for your code.

```
from elementium.drivers.se import SeElements
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en')
se = SeElements(browser)

se.xpath('//input[@name="username"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('username')
se.xpath('//input[@type="password"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('password')
se.xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Log in")]', wait=True, ttl=2).click()
assert se.xpath('//a[text()="Profile"]', wait=True, ttl=2), 'User was not logged in.'
```

The same to Sign Up:

```
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en')
se = SeElements(browser)

se.xpath('//input[@name="emailOrPhone"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('366656')
se.xpath('//input[@name="fullName"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('Alex')
se.xpath('//input[@name="username"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('Alex')
se.xpath('//input[@name="password"]', wait=True, ttl=2).clear().write('password')
se.xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Sign up")]', wait=True, ttl=2).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I only yesterday learned about how to make xpath more efficient and useful. I was copying whole xpath, which changed because of class names.

Comment: You are welcome. If you will have any difficulties, write me.

Answer (score 0):

ssh root@your_server_ip
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
wget sftp://root@localhost/root/Instagram-Follower-Bot/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
scp root@localhost:/root/Instagram-Follower-Bot/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb .
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
google-chrome --version

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

def open_instagram_signup():
    # Setup ChromeDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    try:
        # Navigate to the Instagram signup page
        driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/')

        # Wait for some time to visually confirm navigation
        time.sleep(10)
    finally:
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_instagram_signup()
```